# AngularJS date validation (formats)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I could use some help. I am having input field with `type="text"` and `ng-required="true"`. I am using [datepicker (Angular UI Bootstrap)](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepicker).

If my input is empty, `someForm.someInput.$error` returns `"required":true`, which is okay.
If my input is filled with `"someText"`, `someForm.someInput.$error` returns `"date":true`, which is odd to me.

1. How is this triggered, is this done by directive datepicker? I don't have type="date" or something.*
2. How could I achieve that date in format "dd.MM.yyyy" would be valid?

If I enter `01.01.2015` or `01.13.2015` - this seems to be valid (no `"date":true`) but apparently it isn't. 
I guess current valid format is `"yyyy.MM.dd"`.

Note: I am also using angular locale file, if this is important.

Comment: To validate a date pattern you should use ng-pattern="space for regex expression". After adding this you should have correct validation of the date input.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not sure if this is the answer cause date validation can still be present and I don't know what part of code is triggering this.

Comment: Anybody else with some solution?

Comment: Can you provide the snippet of your code with the input field?

Comment: Did u find any solution to this one? Facing the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that datepicker is using two values. One for model, one for input. This works if you enter date by selecting it from popup, although not working if typing it in input field.

I have solved this issue by putting readonly attribute to input field.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (RoR and AngularJS), I was saving the data into the server the next time when you get the data from the server, the datepicker has {date: true} validation error.

What I did to fix this?
Instead of sending iso8601 format string or UTC format string, I tried returning the milliseconds format

Following example in ruby will clarify what removed the date validation on angular ui bootstrap datetimePicker.

```
my_object.my_timestamp # DID NOT WORK :-(
my_object.my_timestamp.iso8601 # DID NOT WORK :-(

my_object.my_timestamp.to_f * 1000 # WORKED :-)
```

Hope this helps!